# Measure the slope of a triangle relative to a plane

Tags: trigonometry, solid-geometry

Suppose I have a list of vertices that form triangles floating in space. How do I measure the slope of each triangle relative to a flat ground plane?

Comment: find the normal vector to each of the triangular plane.

Comment: for three points $x, y, z$ expressed as vectors, a normal vector is $(y - x) \times (z - x) = x \times y + y \times z + z \times x$

Comment: After I find the normal vector, what do I do? The slope should be a single number, not a vector right?

Answer (score 0):

A point **A** has the coordinates ***(X1,Y1,Z1)***.A point **B** has the coordinates ***(X2,Y2,Z2)***

The slope of an angle **θ** it's **tgθ**.

So, **tgθ=|Y1-Y2|/d** ,where d is the distance between the Y-axes of each point.

Using the Pythagorean theorem ,we find **d=√[ (Z1-Z2)^2 + (X1-X2)^2 ]**

So,the slope is **tgθ=|Y1-Y2|/√[ (Z1-Z2)^2 + (X1-X2)^2 ]** .

I hope I helped you.